# Call javascript callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, anonymous-function

I want to pass an anonymous function as a callback, then call it. I am probably missing something simple, but I just get the error 'Uncaught type error - callback is not a function'.
This is what I am doing - (using jQuery) - I pass the callback as an anonymous function when creating a new object:

```
$('#someid').alphaColorPicker({
            callback: function() {
                console.log("called")
            }
        });
```

Then I call it at some point (or try to):

```
$.fn.alphaColorPicker = function(callback) {

    ...
    ...

    callback(); //this throws the error
}
```

How do I correctly call the callback function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the value you are sending:

```
{ callback: function () { ... } }
```

That isn't a function.

It is an object with a property called `callback` which is a function.

Therefore:

```
callback.callback();
```

---

Or you could pass an actual function instead of an object:

```
$('#someid').alphaColorPicker(function() { console.log("called") });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not directly passing the function, you are passing an object which has `callback` property

make it

```
$.fn.alphaColorPicker = function(options) {

    ...

    options.callback(); //this throws the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you pass into the `alphaColorPicker` is not a callback function but rather a object containing a value that is a callback.

```
{ // When putting it within {} its a new object.
  // Where 'callback' is a member/key of the object.
  callback : function() {
    console.log("called");
}
```

If you instead pass the function directly:

```
$('#someid').alphaColorPicker(function() {
    console.log("called");
});
```

You can call it right away via `callback();`.
If you wish to keep it as an object, you can call it by calling the member of the object instead of trying to call the object as a function:

```
callback.callback();
```

Comment: Thank you, I just kind of figured that out but your answer does explain why I was not getting anywhere - should have used callback.callback(), as you pointed out.

Comment: @ardmark, feel free to mark an answer as correct (and/or upvote) if any of them helped you to solve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Found the problem, should not have passed the function as

```
callback: function() {
                console.log("called")
            }
```

But just like this:

```
    $('#' + boxID).alphaColorPicker(function() {
            console.log("hello")
    });
```

And if I want to pass parameters in, I can do it like this:

```
$('#' + boxID).alphaColorPicker({x:styleName, y:id, callback:function() {
        //do something
}});
```

But I am confused about how to pass parameters in / out like in jQuery event handlers such as:

```
$("#"+boxID).alphaColorPicker({x:styleName, y:this.inputID}, function(e){}
```

});

How do you access the callback here? In my example, in alphaColorPicker callback.x and callback.y are obviously available, but the callback function is passed as an object I can't see how to call it.